# Yoga X390 can't find SIM Card

Tags: 23.04

I have a refurbished X390 and just installed Ubuntu 23.04.
Today I got my second SIM-Card. I put it in an extra Phone and it worked. Now I put it in the Laptop and in the settings I turn on the button at "mobile network". If I turn on the toggle it says "no Sim Card". Anybody got an idea?

```
nmcli device show | grep "GENERAL.DEVICE:"
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp0s20f3
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wwan0at1
```